# Do I use a method or a computed property if I have an integer that is seconds and I want to calculate how many minutes that is?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having trouble figuring out when should I use computed properties over methods.

For example right now I have a property that contains integer number that represents seconds and I would like to transform those seconds to minutes. I can easily create a method that takes the seconds as an argument, calculate seconds/60 and return the result, however, I don't seem to understand how would I do that with a computed property since they don't seem to take arguments.

The way I see it computed properties can only be used for very basic stuff that don't even require arguments. Am I incorrect?

How would I do this if I were using computed properties:

```
    <p>{{ this.secondsToMinutes(120) }}</p>

    secondsToMinutes(seconds) {
        let minutes = seconds/60;

        return minutes
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you should **use computed properties**. There are two reasons:

1. Computed properties are cached yielding a good performance.
2. In terms of readability, computed properties strictly act like getters and are easier to reason about in a long-run.

About readability, if you make sure computed properties should be used only as pure functions without any side-effects like API call and if you agree to this design guideline, then in a large-scale application where you will have thousands of such properties, you can quickly reason about their purpose.

Vue.js docs recommend using them over [methods or watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods).

#### Sample Example

```
let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    data() {
        return {
            durationInseconds: 120
        };
    },
    computed: {
        secondsToMinutes() {
            return this.durationInseconds / 60;
        }
    }
});

<!-- Inside Template -->
<p> {{ secondsToMinutes }} </p>
```

Comment: Is it possible to show me how would I do the code I've applied to my question if I were using computed properties? I just don't see how am I meant to pass an argument to a computed property.